# Data not transfred from form to mysql table (updating of data is not happening)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi all and thanks in advance to all for this

I tired and was unable to find the answer i am looking for an answer. my problem is that i am unable to update the values enterd in the form. I have attached all the files i'm using MYSQL database to fetch data.

what happens is that i'm able to add and delete records from form using ajax and PHP scripts to MYSQL database, but i am not able to update data which was retrived from database. 
the file structure is as follows

**index.php** is a file with ajax functions where it displays form for adding new data to MYSQL using save.php file and list of all records are view without refrishing page (calling load-list.php to view all records from index.php works fine, and save.php to save data from form)

-> **Delete**is an ajax function called from index.php to delete record from mysql database (function calling delete.php works fine)

-> **Update** is an ajax function called from index.php to update data using update-form.php by retriving specific record from mysql tabel, (works fine)

> Problem lies in updating data from
>   update-form.php to update.php (in which
>   update query is wrriten for mysql)

i had tried in many ways at last i had figured out that data is not being transfred from update-form.php to update.php there is a small problem in jquery ajax function where it is not transfering data to update.php page.

can any one correct this ????? i will be greatfull to them.....
please find the link below for all files

[link to get my form files](http://cid-b88405bc51ef157b.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/mysmallform.zip)

Comment: Note this is html renamed to zip

Comment: not sir there are 8 files name
index.php 3,340 kb
delete.php 494 kb
jquery.js 120,763 kb
load-list.php 1,207 kb
save.php 625 kb
style.css 295 kb
update.php 694 kb
update-form.php 1,209 kb

Virus free assurance...
were ziped using winrar... please let me know if you are unable to download..

Comment: Ahaha, I've saved a prompt page! Silly me :) Well I feel not to debug it for you. Just 2 notes: 1. make an AJAX-free update form and send it to the update.php. See what it would say. 2. use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 1):

> "I wrote a program and it isn't working"

The general answer to such a question is only one: **debugging**.
This term stands for a technique that allows a programmer to find an error in the code.
As a matter of fact, debugging take **most of time** spent to develop a program. Go figure.
Asking other people to debug your code for you is to ask them to do your job for you. For free.

If you aren't a programmer, consider to hire one.
If you wannabe-programmer, start to learn debugging as soon as possible
Here is an article to start: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

Since AJAX applications are harder to debug, I'd advice to write your app without AJAX first, make it working, and only then implement AJAX bells and whistles.